# Access the index of a parent listview in a nested repeater in a Nativescript layout

Tags: javascript, arrays, nativescript

I have an array that contains multiple arrays of objects with in it that is returned from a web service, lets call it `var groups`. In my view model it's an observable array.

```
var groups = [
              [{year:"1986", key2: "foo2"}, {year:"1986", key2:"blah"}],
              [{year:"1987", key2: "baz"}, {year:"1987", key2:"beek"}],
              [{year:"1988", key2: "baz"}, {year:"1988", key2:"beek"}]
             ]
```

In my xml I'm trying to nest a `<Repeater>` with in a `<Listview>` such that each array in the `groups` array will be a list item, and each object in the inner arrays will be a repeater item. Problem is I have no clue how to access the index of the parent listview items so that I can reference the correct array in the repeater, and I can't find in the documentation how to access the list index from with in the xml. Does anyone know if this is possible? Here's an example of the xml note the ??? in the repeaters iterator....What can I actually put there?

```
<Listview items="{{ Groups }}">
    <ListView.itemTemplate>
       /* Some other layout content */
      <Repeater items="{{ Groups[parent.index] ??? }}">
        <Repeater.itemTemplate>
          / * the contents of each groups array should display here */
        </Repeater.itemTemplate>
      </Repeater>
    </ListView.itemTemplate> 
</Listview>
```

EDIT: Just to make it more clear, I basically just want to know how to access the Parent list views index from the repeaters `item` attribute. That would allow me to display the correct data in the repeater element.

I'm trying to achieve a separated list such as this below. Each array in the `groups` array is a chunk of data with the same date. So the list view rows (dates) are based on the number of arrays contained in the `groups` array and the data sections below each date are populated from the data within each of those arrays.

[image: I'm trying to achieve a separated list such as this below. Each array in the <code>groups</code> array is a chunk of data with the same date. So the list view rows (dates) are based on the number of arrays contained in the <code>groups</code> array and the data sections below each date are populated from the data within each of those arrays.]

Comment: There is a plugin for sectioned list-views .. however even with this plugin you will still need to normalize the way you provide your data in order to avoid searching for the nested index https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-sectioned-list-view

Comment: Yeah unfortunately that plugin does not look to support android.

Answer (score 2):

In `NativeScript` is not possible to get index of the selected `item` in `Repeater`. However one possible decision could be to set unique `id` for example to `Label` and to attach `tap` even to it. When one of the `Label` has been clicked, you could get its unique `id`. I am attaching example for this option.

**main-page.xml**

```
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="onPageLoaded">
        <ListView id="listview" items="{{ myItems }}" itemTap="listViewItemTap">
            <ListView.itemTemplate>
                <StackLayout>

                  <Repeater items="{{ myItem2 }}" >
                    <Repeater.itemsLayout>
                      <WrapLayout />
                    </Repeater.itemsLayout>
                    <Repeater.itemTemplate>
                      <Label text="{{ $value.item }}" id="{{$value.key}}" margin="10" onTap="test"/>
                    </Repeater.itemTemplate>
                  </Repeater>
                </StackLayout>
            </ListView.itemTemplate>
        </ListView>
</Page>
```

**main-page.js**

```
var observable_array_1 = require("data/observable-array");
function onPageLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    var array = new observable_array_1.ObservableArray();
    var listView = page.getViewById('listview');
    array.push({ myItem2: [{ item: "test1", key: "1" }, { item: "test1", key: 'j' }, { item: "test1", key: "3" }] });
    array.push({ myItem2: [{ item: "test6", key: "6" }, { item: "test4", key: "4" }, { item: "test5", key: "5" }] });
    page.bindingContext = { myItems: array };

}
exports.onPageLoaded = onPageLoaded;
function listViewItemTap(args) {
    var itemIndex = args.index;
    var object = args.object;
    console.log(itemIndex);
}
exports.listViewItemTap = listViewItemTap;
function test(args) {
    console.log(args.object.get('id'));
}
exports.test = test;
```

Comment: In my use case the items in the repeater do not need to be tapped by the user. The only reason I need the index of the parent Listview item is so that I can display the objects contained in the Groups arrays. Would this method allow that?

Comment: I've made some additional edits to hopefully make the question a little more clear.

Comment: In my sample project above all groups array have been displayed in the `ListView` in the same order just as they have been  pushed in the `ObservableArray`. In my opinion my solution will solve your problem with displaying the data.

Comment: Ok, I will try that out. I've also added an image of what I'm trying to achieve just to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

As NativeScript indeed can not provide indexing inside the nested repeater and based on the **example of Nikolay Tsonev** it will be a lot easier to just convert your jagged array to array with JSON objects. Here is what you need to do for [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37703666/4936697) to work with your array.

```
var groups = [
      [{year:"1986", key2: "foo2"}, {year:"1986", key2:"blah"}],
      [{year:"1987", key2: "baz"}, {year:"1987", key2:"beek"}],
      [{year:"1988", key2: "baz"}, {year:"1988", key2:"beek"}]
];

var resultArray = new ObservableArray();

groups.forEach(subgroup => {
    var jsonArg1 = new Object();
    jsonArg1["myItem2"] = subgroup;
    resultArray.push(jsonArg1);
});
```

However you have also another solution - you can provide totally diffferent binding source to your nested repeater via  $parents[Page].someDataModel
For example:

```
// page.xml
<ListView items="{{ items }}">
    <ListView.itemTemplate>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label text="{{ $value }}" />
            <TextField text="{{ $parents['ListView'].test, $parents['ListView'].test }}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ListView.itemTemplate>
</ListView>

// page.js
viewModel.set("items", [1, 2, 3]);
viewModel.set("test", "Test for parent binding!");
```

This as well will require for you to manually convert your two-dimensional array into something with more suitable form. More about **$parents** this [here](https://github.com/dmccuskey/nativescript-docs/blob/master/bindings.md)

Comment: So in your first example would each array in the `groups` array become an Object? In which case the groups array would contain three objects and then those objects would contain their current contents? I have also added an image of what I'm trying to accomplish.